# Does OS X support a mechanism for security updates similar to apt-get?

Tags: macos, software-update

I have used brew to install software, is there a similar command line mechanism to download the OS's security updates?

Comment: Take a look at the manual for `softwareupdate`.

Answer (score 4):

**`softwareupdate`** can perform updates to macOS.
List updates with `softwareupdate -l` and install recommended updates with

```
sudo softwareupdate -ir
```

where `-i` installs specified updates and `-r` selects all recommended updates.

Comment: Warning: by default, `softwareupdate` does not automatically restart the system even when when an update requires it. You need to either add the `-R` flag, or notice that the update has a "[restart]" suffix in the list and restart manually after installing.